# Manipulative materials to teach functions

Tags: algebra, functions

I am looking for manipulative materials  to teach functions (the concepts including domain, image, etc.) and kind of function (affine, quadratic, exponential logarithmic, polynomial, trigonometric) thanks!

iam looking for concrete manipulaives. there are plenty of digital ones: –

Comment: desmos may have something

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Narrowing your question down to something less broad might attract some answers. Ideas to consider: In what way to you want to "teach functions"? What do you expect students to do with these manipulatives, or are you looking for things a teacher can use to demonstrate a concept/technique? Are you wanting physical objects or web apps? What do you mean "teach...kind of function"? Like, learning to recognize different types via graphs, formulas, numerical data? I can't imagine answering this question without more specificity in the request. Could you add more?

Comment: @NickC, iam looking for concrete manipulaives. there are plenty of digital ones:

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi I recommend adding that (and more!) to the question text.